# DevExpress ASPxTreeList CommandColumn Buttons Size

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using DevExpress `ASPxTreeList` to display data and I have used some custom `linkbuttons` in `TreeListDataColumn` and in `TreeListCommandColumn` I have Placed `EditButton` and `DeleteButton`.
Now, I need to increase the size of `Edit` and `Delete` Buttons.
[image]

and my `TreeList` code :

```
<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="TreeList_Branch_Departments" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ChildBranchID" ParentFieldName="ParentBranchID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Theme="BlackGlass" Height="410px"
        Width="534px" Font-Size="11px" Font-Names="calibri" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="TreeList_Branch_Departments_HtmlDataCellPrepared" OnCommandColumnButtonInitialize="TreeList_Branch_Departments_CommandColumnButtonInitialize">
        <Columns>
            <dx:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="ChildBranchName" CellStyle-Font-Bold="true" CellStyle-Font-Names="calibri" CellStyle-Font-Size="Medium" VisibleIndex="0" />
            <dx:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="p" VisibleIndex="1" Visible="false"></dx:TreeListDataColumn>
            <dx:TreeListDataColumn Name="BRANCH">
                <DataCellTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_CreateBranch" runat="server" ForeColor="DeepPink" Font-Underline="true" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ChildBranchID")%>' OnClick="Btn_CreateBranch_Click">New Branch</asp:LinkButton>
                </DataCellTemplate>
            </dx:TreeListDataColumn>
            <dx:TreeListDataColumn Name="DEPT">
                <DataCellTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_CreateDept" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="DarkOrange" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ChildBranchID") %>' OnClick="Btn_CreateDept_Click">New Department</asp:LinkButton>
                </DataCellTemplate>
            </dx:TreeListDataColumn>
            <dx:TreeListCommandColumn>
                <EditButton Visible="True" />
                <DeleteButton Visible="True" />
            </dx:TreeListCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
        <SettingsBehavior ExpandCollapseAction="NodeDblClick" />
        <SettingsSelection AllowSelectAll="true" Enabled="true" Recursive="true" />
        <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedNode="true" AllowSort="false" AllowDragDrop="false" />
    </dx:ASPxTreeList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit and Delete buttons are under Command Column. You can increase the size by adding tag CellStyle under tag TreeListCommandColumn

```
...
<dx:TreeListCommandColumn>
   <CellStyle Font-Size="20px">
   </CellStyle>
</dx:TreeListCommandColumn>
...
```